# Chrome not displaying the exact RGB color

Tags: google-chrome, rgb

I am out of ideas what is happening here in Chrome (109 on win 10), hope someone could help me understand...

Lets say I have a simple .html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="background:#ff0000">
</html>
```

Running it in browser and measuring the rendered color with built-in color picker (or any photoshop-like software) I am getting **#ff1806** instead of **#ff0000**. Same case with Edge. However, Firefox renders pure red as expected.

Is this a chrome bug to report, or chrome/system custom color scheme settings that's applied somewhere?

Comment: I assume it has to do with colour management. Probably your laptop has a larger gamut (and so colour space) then sRGB (which it is the base of browser). So when displaying images, browsers uses different *intent* (Firefox: "saturation intent", other browser something about "perceptual" or "absolute": so different coluter will show similar colour).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Just managed to find the chrome settings, and answered myself below

Answer (score 2):

This is related to Chrome [Force color profile](https://chrome://flags/#force-color-profile) flag and (likely) my BenQ monitor. More interesting reading on [BenQ knowledge center](https://www.benq.com/en-us/knowledge-center/knowledge/web-browsers-color-management.html).

The issue can be fixed by changing #force-color-profile flag to "sRGB" (changed from Default)